# How many instances of Tracer should I use with opencensus?

Tags: trace, opencensus

The [documentation](https://opencensus.io/api/python/trace/usage.html) on the `Tracer` class gives some examples but does not provide recommendations on what is the desired lifecycle of a `Tracer` instance. It is possible to reuse the same instance for multiple traces. Should I practice that or should I create an new instance every time? Are there performance considerations or other caveats?

One reason to create a new instance could be setting a desired operation ID through `SpanContext(trace_id=...)` however the same can be achieved through

`span.context_tracer.span_context.trace_id = my_trace_id`

What is the best practice here?